# using system(calls) in C program whit privileges

Tags: root, expect, sudo, privileges

I wrote a program in C that starts a further program written in expect. the program in expect provides a numerical output for each execution step, in order to identify an error and return it to the C program that performs the visualization through uart. within the C program, I launch the execution of Expect: `ret = system ("sudo / usr / bin / expect ./expTest.exp ... arguments ...");`

The program is compiled in gcc and runs perfectly if I log in as root and launch it from the shell. But if I start it automatically at start up with rc.local, the C program is executed in every detail, at the launch of the Expect, I have an execution error, as if I had problems with root permissions or something like that . I can not see the error but I see, through a uart port connected to the C program that the sub program in Expect is not executed after launch.

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow`, Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: hi, Hill, now it's comprensible :D?

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help